# identifying specific UITextField with delegate

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have two UITextfields with delegates.
I need to be able to identify between them in the fund below  so just just one of them will open datePicker (commented for now). How would I do that?

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //******************************************
        //******************************************
        //uncomment this for date to work
        /*
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        textField.inputView = datePicker
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
 */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- Add tags and check `if textField.tag == 100 { ...`
- Add an `IBOutlet` for one of them and check `if textField == myTextField { ...`

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could handle this via comparing the text field that is handed into the delegate method.

Something to the effect of:

```
if myTextField {
do action
}
```